# Text in float layout

Tags: html, layout

I am new to HTML and CSS, and I have a problem that I can't solve. I created a simple 2 column layout, where both columns have the same height depending on content of columns. As you can see, the column1 works perfectly fine but I have problem with column2. I have no idea why that text is not on same level as in column1 and when I change width of my browser window ( shrink it) text in column2 appears out of yellow column. I would understand if width of column 1 would be 100% that it would take it's place but it's not. also when I put larget text into column 2 , that text wont spread across whole width of that yellow column even when the width is larger. I need to somehow put it properly in designe place but I don't know what am I doing wrong.

```css
body {
 background-color: #eeeeee;
}
header {

 text-align: center;
 height: 80px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #eeeeee;
}
#stredovyObal {
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-right: 10%;
 width: 80%;
}
#container2 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
}
#container1 {
    float:left;
    width: 250px;
    background:white;
    position:relative;
}
#col1 {
 text-align: center;
    float:left;
    width: 250px;
    position:relative;

}
#col2 {
text-align: justify;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 150%;
}
    
footer {
float: left;
 width: 100%;
 height: 1em;
 background-color: #007501;
  text-align: right;
 color: white;
}    
footer p {
 text-align: right;
 color: white;
 font: bold;
 font: fantasy;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
 <header></header> 
    <div id="stredovyObal">
    <div id="container2"> 
        <div id="container1">
            <div id="col1">Column 1</div>
                          <div id="col2">Column 2</div>

        </div>
    </div>  <footer></footer> 
    </div>



     
  </body>
</html>
```

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make  `display:inline-flex;` your  `#container1`.What `inline-flex` does is it displays an element as an inline-level flex container.And make those white column width for `25%` and yellow one for `75%` to create `100%`, and make sure to make, `body` `margin` and `padding` to `0`;

Here's the CSS

```css
body {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
header {

    text-align: center;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
#stredovyObal {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    width: 80%;
}

#container1 {
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    background:white;
    position:relative;
  display:inline-flex;
}
#col1, #col2 {
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#col1 {
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
    position:relative;

}
#col2 {
text-align: justify;
    float:left;
    width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    background:yellow;
}

footer {
float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1em;
    background-color: #007501;
        text-align: right;
    color: white;
}    
footer p {
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    font: bold;
    font: fantasy;

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
 <header></header> 
    <div id="stredovyObal">
    <div id="container2"> 
        <div id="container1">
            <div id="col1">Column 1</div>
                          <div id="col2">Column 2</div>

        </div>
    </div>  <footer></footer> 
    </div>



     
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPRjBy

Comment: thank you very much for your help! Works perfectly! I wouldn't figure this out without you, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Styles... #col1 is 25% width, and #col2 is 75% width, together they make a total of 100% width of #container1

```
body {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
header {

    text-align: center;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
#stredovyObal {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    width: 80%;
}

#container1 {
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    background:white;
    position:relative;
}
#col1, #col2 {
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#col1 {
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
    position:relative;

}
#col2 {
text-align: justify;
    float:left;
    width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    background:yellow;
}

footer {
float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1em;
    background-color: #007501;
        text-align: right;
    color: white;
}    
footer p {
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    font: bold;
    font: fantasy;

}
```

Then your html...

```
<header></header> 
    <div id="stredovyObal">

        <div id="container1">
            <div id="col1">Column 1</div>
            <div id="col2">Column 2</div>

        </div>
   <footer></footer> 
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n2qgbr5z/2/

Comment: thank you for your input but unfortunately this way it will lose its ability of same height columns. When I shrink the height of my browser window the yellow column is not the same size as the white one :(

Comment: No problem you could always do something like this instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/n2qgbr5z/6/